# Ansible: build a dictionary (which values are lists) from a single list

Tags: ansible

I need something that looks trivial but I can't handle it. I have a list in a variable like that:

```json
"ansible_mounts": [
    {
        "device": "/device1",
        "mount": "/"
    },
    {
        "device": "/device1",
        "mount": "/home"
    },
    {
        "device": "/device2",
        "mount": "/boot"
    }
]
```

I need a dictionary with the device as key and the mounts as values. I don't understand how to get a list as a value, I just know how to get a single item (and so in each loop the last item is overriden):

```yaml
- name: Getting all the mounted filesystems (by device)
  ansible.builtin.set_fact: 
    filesystems_by_device: "{{ item }}"
  with_items:
    - "{{ ansible_mounts | items2dict(key_name='device', value_name='mount') }}"
```

Output is:

```json
"filesystems_by_device": {
    "device2": "/boot",
    "device1": "/home"
}
```

I would need:

```json
"filesystems_by_device": {
    "device2": [ "/boot" ],
    "device1": [ "/", "/home" ]
}
```

I understand for example how to build a list from a filtered one, and I probably need to apply something similar to my dictionary:

```yaml
- name: List from filtered one
  set_fact:
    foo: "{{ foo + [item] }}"
  with_items:
    - "{{ ansible_mounts }}"
  when: item.mount in another_list
  vars:
    foo: []
```

I've tried a lot of things but I'm lost with that syntax.

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually not as trivial as it looks and I don't think there is a solution without looping in a task (as you already tried) unless by developing a custom filter. Here is how I achieved this in plain standard ansible.

- create a loop over the unique name of devices in your list.
- set_fact for each item extracting values of the mount points for that device

The demo playbook:

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false

  vars:
    "ansible_mounts": [
      {
        "device": "/device1",
        "mount": "/"
      },
      {
        "device": "/device1",
        "mount": "/home"
      },
      {
        "device": "/device2",
        "mount": "/boot"
      }
    ]

  tasks:
    - name: Construct the needed datastructure
      set_fact:
        filesystems_by_device: >-
          {{
            filesystems_by_device | default({})
            | combine({
              item: ansible_mounts | selectattr('device', 'eq', item) | map(attribute='mount') | list
            })
          }}
      loop: "{{ ansible_mounts | map(attribute='device') | unique | sort }}"

    - name: Show result
      debug:
        var: filesystems_by_device
```

The result:

```
PLAY [localhost] ***********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Construct the needed datastructure] **********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=/device1)
ok: [localhost] => (item=/device2)

TASK [Show result] *********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "filesystems_by_device": {
        "/device1": [
            "/",
            "/home"
        ],
        "/device2": [
            "/boot"
        ]
    }
}

PLAY RECAP *****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Copy/pasting your playbook for testing, I do not obtain the same result (ansible 2.9.13) :
ok: [localhost] => (item=/device1)
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"msg": "|combine expects dictionaries, got \"{'/device1': <generator object do_map at 0x7f032e1e9308>}\""}

Comment: Right, my playbook works correctly in ansible 2.10. Juste edited with a fix that will work everywhere

Comment: Perfect thanks! Didn't have time to analyse the error you've already provided a solution